# document.domain same origin policy not working

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

Despite of the fact that I have seen many articles (including in stackoverflow) demonstrating up how to bypass *javascript's same origin policy* assigning **document.domain** property, its not working. I also read in W3C specs that document.domain property is read-only and not all browsers accept setting it and I think that is the cause I can't get that working!

I have a page (domain d1.y.com.br) and I need to invoke a button in an embedded iframe's page (domain d2.x.com.br). I'm setting the parent document.domain attribute to subdomain 'x.com.br' but I'm still receiving the 'access denied' error message in firebug console.

I have also read about JSONP but its not the case here. I really need to interact with iframe's DOM and not only get data from there (using proxy service).

Does really exist any way to bypass same origin policy to interact with the iframe's DOM ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to send data between iframes (especially across domains) is using postMessage().   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

That effectively "bypasses" the problem by having the recipient of the message verify that the caller has the correct domain - based on whatever rules it wants.

Comment: I agree. The problem is that in my case the embedded page is not collaborative with mine, that is, the embedded page is not expecting any message (sent via window.postMessage()) from parent page. Even if it was, window.postMessage() is HTML5 compliant and my page is not.

Comment: What I need to do is attach an event listener on a button's event existing on iframe's DOM and, as soon as this button is clicked, I send another event to parent DOM. I need to capture an event in the iframe's DOM and, to do this, I need to gain access first (what is blocked by the same origin policy because its cross-domain)

Comment: Gotcha.  In that case you are doing something which is pretty much exactly what the same-origin policy is designed to prevent.  IMO your only viable option would be to proxy and modify the page to include whatever you need.  Obviously you need to make sure that what you are doing does not violate the terms of the site or create other non-technical/human problems.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately I need to implement exactly this behavior. I thought to proxy the load of the page content and then append the html content to my own page but I would end up with many problems like not loading <script/> imports existing in the the external (loaded) page.

Comment: Solution to that issue might be as simple as: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: Can you explain the solution?

Comment: bgp! GOTCHA! I will try this . THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Proxy the page and modify it to include your script and also include a &lt;base href=""/> so that the external references on the page are based from it's original URL.  (Haven't tested it, but it's worth a shot.)

Comment: (Please be sure to accept correct answers and upvote useful ones ;)